Trying to diy these Roman Blinds - anyone know what to do?
Trying to figure out why these Roman Blinds aren't pulling up or down when I pull the continuous loop chain (I am learning all these terms for the first time). I 'think' I need to replace the spools (or spool locks) and restring the whole thing? I watched a couple of videos of how to diy simple Roman Blinds that seemed easy but this has multiple mechanisms. All the cords are locked into place at set lengths using these orb-lock-things. Even identifying the brand would be helpful. Photos here: https://imgur.com/a/tX0SQ7T
